# Unity 2D: How to fix Velocity related bug for Vector2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm still new to developing 2D games with Unity Engine. A few years ago, I programmed a Breakout clone, following this [tutorial here](https://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-arkanoid-game). It all works fine. But if the player hits the ball with an edge of the paddle and moving the paddle at the same time into the same direction too fast, the ball's velocity increases to a very high speed. See the animated gif I included:

[image: Unity bug]

To find out, what's causing the problem, I added some temporary code, that saved the velocity to a text file. This is what the velocity property of the ball looks like:

```
(-16.9, 98.6)
```

To change that, I tried adding this code:

```
// file: Ball.cs

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name == "racket")
        {
            float x = hitFactor(transform.position,
                          col.transform.position,
                          col.collider.bounds.size.x);
            Vector2 dir = new Vector2(x, 1).normalized;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = dir * speed;

            // my addition
            if(GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().velocity.x < 0)
            {
                GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().velocity.x = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

But it didn't work. What can I do to change the ball's velocity.right value to a positive number in this case?

Comment: well you could just adjust the speed not the actual values

Comment: I would probably just leave a script on the ball itself that handles this and always throttles/accelerates in order to keep the same speed

Answer (score 0):

First note, please don't use GetComponent for every single modification. Not sure if you're copying a tutorial but its bad habit, simply add a variable and use that like this:

```
using ...

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RigidBody2D rb;

    void Start() {
        // set rb to the rigidbody component
        rb = GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();
    }
    // access the rigidbody anywhere using rb. For example:
    rb.velocity...
}
```

My next recommendation is to do what your doing without using code, simply make sure your balls Rigidbody has a gravity scale of 0, then create a 2D physics material (Right Click > 2D > Physics Material 2D) and set the friction to 0, and the bounciness to 1. This will now mean that the ball will bounce off of any surface without losing any velocity. The only problem with this method is that when played the ball will stay still, so instead you can use this script I made, to fire the ball on start or whenever you want really. I've added comments so you can try and understand what certain things do as you said you're still new, if you don't understand certain things though. Reply and I'll be able to help!

```
using UnityEngine;

// we can use RequireComponent so that this script will only work if a RigidBody2D is present.
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    // add some customizable variables.
    [Range(0, 360)] public float fireAngle = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private bool fireRandomDirection = false;
    public float fireSpeed;
    // declare our rigidbody variable.
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        // get the rigidbody component and assign it to rb.
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        
        // call the function using the variables above.
        Fire(fireAngle, fireSpeed);
    }

    // we make this void public so we can fire the ball from any other script.
    public void Fire(float angle, float speed) {
        // if fireRandomDirection is true (checked) we set the angle to a random number between 0 and 360.
        if (fireRandomDirection) {
            angle = Random.Range(0, 360);
        }
        // set the balls z rotation to 0 on the x and y, and angle on the z
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
        // now its rotated we apply our speed to the balls velocity in its up direction.
        rb.velocity = transform.up * speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: `rb = new RigidBody2D();` .. that's even worse ;) You never will want to instantiate any component using `new` .. there is a limited set of `UnityEngine.Object` based types that allow that (e.g. `GameObject` and `Texture2D` ...) most have either a specific factory method or - in this case of components - it doesn't make sense at all to create a standalone instance without being attached to any GameObject

Comment: Also in general for a sphere the rotation shouldn't really matter ;) You can just use `Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle) * Vector3.up * speed` instead ... then of course your implementation doesn't in any way address OP's code and use case  ... the question is not how to fire the ball into a random direction but rather how to avoid the ball going to fast in OP's code ;)

Comment: "rb = new RigidBody2D(); .. that's even worse ;) You never will want to instantiate any component using new" Where did I say that? I don't see it in my answer.

Comment: oh yeah I see it, that was a mistake, i deleted it after.

Comment: and I put the rotation so he could set a custom rotation that the ball lanches when the game begins.